# Serial port telegrams timestamping on ARM embedded Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I want to build an ethernet based distributed measurement system with embedded NXP i.MX 6 ULL boards (measurment nodes).
Measurment data is taken from a serial ineterface with a baudrate of 9600. For each incoming measurement telegram (~30 bytes) a timestamp must be taken/added to the data.
There will be up to 20 boards in the network. System time of the boards will be synchronized with LinuxPTP protocol.

There is a requirement for the measurement data to have a relative time accuracy between the nodes' measurment data of maximum 1 msec.

My questions:

- How could I achieve that accuracy in linux?
- Do I need PREEMPT_RT?
- Must timestamps need to be taken in an own serial kernel module (interrupt handling) or does userspace implementation do the job?
- How to prioritize serial interrupts?

So far I only started to setup the LinuxPTP

Comment: You try to kill the fly using a 150mm howitzer. It is a job for small uC running RTOS

Comment: Yes you are right of course. with this description. I have to say that the board will be a platform to have more features to come in future. (OPC-UA, WebServices etc.)

Comment: Even though consider using RTOS, like Zephyr.